# Finding string index of a tag in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

Does BeautifulSoup provide a method to get the string index of a tag or its text within the HTML string it comes from?

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'lxml')
```

Is there a way to know the string index inside `html_doc` where `soup.p` (`<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's Story</b></p>`) starts? Or where its text (`The Dormouse's story`) starts?

EDIT: The expected index for `soup.p` would be 63, i.e. `html_doc.index('''<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>''')`. The expected index for its text would be 83. I am not using `str.index()` since the returned index might not correspond to the tag in question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are doing some web scraping.
I suggest you check out [XPath](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp) - Google around for XPath libraries in the language you are coding in.

Using XPath selectors, you can find text elements like:

```
("//text()[contains(.,"The Dormouse's story")]")
```

From here on, it is only a matter of selecting its parent class if you need the paragraph element.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The Dormouse's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
</body>
</html>
"""
def findall(patt, s):
    '''Yields all the positions of the pattern patt in the string s.'''
    i = s.find(patt)
    while i != -1:
        yield i
        i = s.find(patt, i+1)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
x = str(soup)
y = str(soup.find("p", {'class':'title'}))
print([(i, x[i:i+len(y)]) for i in findall(y, x)])
```

Comment: What if there are multiple occurrences of exactly the same tag? Does a BeautifulSoup tag object keep a position within the string it is parsed from, just like a lexer does?

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this.

```
print(soup.find("p").text)
```

The output is,

```
The Dormouse's story
```

Can change the `html_doc` content for verify the code logic.

Change the `html_doc` like this.

```
html_doc = """
<html><head><title>The EEEE's story</title></head>
<body>
<p class="title"><b>The Dormouse's story</b></p>
</body>
</html>
"""
```

The code had the same output with above.